# Openlayers : dynamically add vector to existing feature

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I create a feature from a gpx file :

```
var gpxFeatures = (new OlFormat.GPX()).readFeatures(GPXSTRING,{
                dataProjection:'EPSG:4326',
                featureProjection:'EPSG:3857'
            });
```

Now I wish to dynamically add a vector to this feature. I know both extremity of the vector.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.

O do not add the vector to the feature but I create a new feature and add it to the layer.

```
var vectorFeature = new OlFeature({
                        geometry: new OlGeom.LineString([OlProj.fromLonLat(previousLastKnownPosition), OlProj.fromLonLat(newPosition)])
                    });

layer.getSource().addFeatures([vectorFeature, pointFeature]);
```